# How do I convert JSON string date to a custom format date?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ng-filter

Hi I would like to know how do I convert the JSON string date which comes from a response to format like **"8/24/2016".** I made a dateFilter.js bit it didn't work out as I expected so here's what I tried.

Here's the dateFilter.js (Actually it didn't work. Error: data recursion)

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .filter('date', function ($filter) {

            return function (input) {

                if (input == null) {

                    return "";
                    }
                var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd/MM/yyyy');

                return _date.toUpperCase();
            };
        });
})();
```

Here's how I get the JSON with a service (*The code is not complete since I want to show how did I get the response.*)

```
function GetEmpDetails(successcallback, failcallback) {

            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:2222/api/GetEmployees/GetEmployeeDetails',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            $http(req).then(successcallback, failcallback);
        }
```

The controller.js

```
(function initController() {

    EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
        $scope.employeeDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);

        //console.log(res.data);

        }
    });
```

And finally applying the filter to html.

```
<table id="basic-datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100">
   <thead style="text-align:match-parent">
       <tr>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">First Name</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">Last Name</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Date Of Birth</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Gender</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Email</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Mobile</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:190px">Designation</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Date of Join</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">NIC</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Dept. Name</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="emp in employeeDetails.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))" style="text-align:center">
           <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.lname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.DOB | date}}</td> //applying the filter
           <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.mobile_no}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.date_of_join | date}}</td> //applying the filter
           <td>{{emp.nic}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.department_name}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So how would I do this is there's any other way of conversion.

> Final note: right now without the filter: 7/25/2016 12:00:00 AM  want
>   to convert to 7/25/2016

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you try {{emp.DOB | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}

Comment: You might wanna clear up all the irrelevant code and keep only the required things.

Comment: It's not a "JSON string date" but just a string. JSON does not declare any date data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this code. I think this solves your problem:

```
<td>{{emp.DOB | dateFormat}}</td>
```

Angular Filter :

```
.filter('dateFormat', function() {
    return function(dt) {
        var dt = new Date(dt);
        return (dt.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dt.getDate()+'/'+dt.getFullYear();
    };
  })
```

Comment: Thanks :D. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the string to actual Date and then apply built in date filter:

In your controller:

```
$scope.convertToDate = function(date){
      var dateOut = new Date(date);
      return dateOut;
};
```

In your html:

```
<td ng-bind="convertToDate(date) |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></td>
```

Another option can be using `moment.js` in your filter:

```
 moment(input, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Besides, the reason your filter might not be working is its name. Try changing to anything else, like `myDate`.

**UPDATE**

I think I know why you were getting `recursion` error! It is because of the name of your custom filter! Your filter is called `date` and the angular's built in filter is also called `date`. Maybe they ended up calling each other and got stuck in recursion. Just changing the name should do the trick.

Comment: Hi There's a recurring error saying: too much recursion :( any advice?

Comment: @AshaneAlvis which option did you try? are all of them resulting in the same error?

Comment: Hi @Jahongir, ti2005 answer worked for me. Thanks for reaching and helping me out.

Comment: @AshaneAlvis great! See my update for some clarification.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just simply changed the name of the filter to 'myDate' and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using npm module moment.js. i have created a fiddle. have a look at this.

```
var date = moment("7/25/2016 12:00:00 AM").date();
var month = moment("7/25/2016 12:00:00 AM").month();
var year = moment("7/25/2016 12:00:00 AM").year();
console.log(''+month+'/'+ date + '/'+ year);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/1jq7o2uq/